# SQL Server Reporting Server - MS Access Data Source

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, reporting-services, oledb

I found [this resource](https://www.xtivia.com/sql-server-how-to-setup-a-data-source-in-ssrs-to-ms-access-ms-excel-and-csv-files/), installed the 64 bit drivers, and have configured a data source in Report Manager to connect to a MS Access 2010 project. I keep getting an "Unspecified Error" when I test the connection. I did some more digging, and found [this resource](http://visakhm.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-solve-microsoftaceoledb120-error.html). I'm unable to follow those steps, as the report server I'm working with was configured to be strictly a report server, and not a Database Engine. If there's a way to run a T-SQL query on this configuration, SSMS doesn't seem to want to let me do it.

What I'm looking for - does anyone have any experience with the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB connection string on a non-database-engine Report Server?

I'm running SQL Server 2012 Enterprise, and Windows Server 2012.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your question. You seem want to develop reporting services reports against an MS Access database but you make no mention of SSDT (sql services data tool) which is the tool used to develop and publish SSRS reports. Do you have SSDT installed?

Comment: I'm using report builder 3.0. I have reports already created against SQL Server and Oracle data, so that component is all set.